# Find all file names that match a pattern

Tags: regex, r

I am trying to find a way to list all file names in a folder that matches this pattern :

```
20131106XXXXX.pdf
```

The prefix is the date, and the content and length of `XXXX` vary across files, and I only care about pdf files.

Anyone could advise a way to do this?

Comment: Is it actual `X` or could it be any alpha character?

Comment: sorry, I should be more specific. XXXX here means characters that might be in other language(simplified Chinese).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this

```
list.files(path="./yourdir",pattern="[[:digit:]]{8}.*\\.pdf")
```

Comment: thanks, can I specify the 8 digit number here? Say, I want the prefix to be exact '20131106'

Comment: yes, the pattern would match any 8 digit number followed by 0 or more arbitrary characters, and extension .pdf. Replace it with "20131106.*\\.pdf" to match only files starting with 20131106. Check ?regex for more info on regular expressions.

Answer (score 3):

You can use regex.

```
files <- dir(pattern="^[0-9]{8}.*\\.pdf")
```